# Unit testing IoJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a standard framework for unit testing on IOJS? I'm trying to test server-side code that uses ES6 features. Currently I'm trying to use Mocha, which unfortunately is hard-coded to utilize node as it's platform. This wouldn't be so much of a problem - I could just use a transpiler - however I am also using the `koa` library, which makes extensive use of ES6 generators.

Unfortunately, mocha compilers *do not* transpile node_modules, which means I am unable to test any files that utilize the `koa` module.

It also seems fairly counterproductive for me to write my code for use on iojs but be forced to use node to test it.

I did at the io.js tag but this appears to be synonymized with the node one as I am unable to actually select it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are depend from `koa` which doesn't work on `node` you have to use `iojs`.
So, your question is how to run mocha under the `iojs`. Try this

```
iojs ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
```

Here is more thoughts in [issue #1498](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1498) in mocha repository

Comment: I've been trying to use iojs - although I was trying to run the shell file in `node_modules/.bin`. Didn't realize there was a distinct mocha runner inside of it's node modules folder. I'll try it out and report back.